# HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed() method is getting called twice during Session timeout

Tags: spring, servlets, tomcat8

I am trying to log a message whenever HTTP Session is destroyed.
I am using **Spring Boot, Spring Security and Tomcat 8** (embedded) in this web application.

During session timeout, **sessionDestroyed() method is getting called 2 times**, so my message is logged twice.

I checked the session ID and **session id is SAME** during both invocations.

This is how my code looks like...

```
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
```

...

```
        @Component
        public class MySessionListener implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener, ApplicationContextAware {
            @Autowired(required = false)
            SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

and sessionDestroyed() is below.

```
@Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();

        SecurityContextImpl springSecurityContext = (SecurityContextImpl)session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
        if(springSecurityContext!=null){
            Authentication authentication = springSecurityContext.getAuthentication();
            LdapUserDetails userDetails = (LdapUserDetailsImpl)authentication.getPrincipal();

            WebAuthenticationDetails WebAuthenticationDetails = (WebAuthenticationDetails)authentication.getDetails();
            String userIp = WebAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress();

            Log.info(userDetails.getUsername(),userIp,timestamp,"timeout or logout","session destroyed");

        }

       sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(se.getSession().getId());
        logger.info("Due to timeout/logout Session is Destroyed : Session ID is..." + session.getId());

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated...

**Note:** I noticed this issue was a defect in **Tomcat 5**, I don't think that defect is still unfixed in Tomcat 8.

Reference: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Tomcat's bug. It is a bug specific to my application.

I found below code within my application.

```
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
        ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext().addListener(this);
    } else {
        //Either throw an exception or fail gracefully, up to you
        throw new RuntimeException("Must be inside a web application context");
    }
}
```

Below line adding current listener into Servlet Context.

```
getServletContext().addListener(this);
```

As **Spring already added** this listener (MySessionListener) into Servlet Context, adding listener for the 2nd time leaded into 2nd sessionDestroyed() method call by Tomcat's org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession class.

Tomcat's Source code is for reference.

```
package org.apache.catalina.session;

public class StandardSession implements HttpSession, Session, Serializable {

....

public void expire(boolean notify) {

.....

.....

 Object listeners[] = context.getApplicationLifecycleListeners();
                    if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
                        HttpSessionEvent event =
                            new HttpSessionEvent(getSession());
                        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
                            int j = (listeners.length - 1) - i;
                            if (!(listeners[j] instanceof HttpSessionListener))
                                continue;
                            HttpSessionListener listener =
                                (HttpSessionListener) listeners[j];
                            try {
                                context.fireContainerEvent("beforeSessionDestroyed",
                                        listener);
                                listener.sessionDestroyed(event);
                                context.fireContainerEvent("afterSessionDestroyed",
                                        listener);
                            }

....
....
```

Taken from above source code of Tomcat..

So, listeners[] contains duplicate entry of MySessionListener.

```
Object listeners[] = context.getApplicationLifecycleListeners();
```